# get position of view with respect to top-most parent in android

Tags: android, android-layout

To get a view relative to its parent, I can use `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getTop()`, and `getBottom()`. But how do I get a view relative to the top-most parent of the layout file?
So say my eve layout is `RelativeLayout`. Then say inside eve I have a number of nested layouts. And then deep within the hierarchy I have a EditText view. How do I get the location of the EditText view with respect to eve?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information? The position relative to the root wont help much in positioning the view inside nested children as a views position is always related to its immediate parent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find out absolute view location, you can use `view.getLocationOnScreen()` or `view.getLocationInWindow()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_id);
View parent = (View)target.getParent();
int x = target.getLeft();
int y = target.getTop();
while(parent != null){
   x += parent.getLeft();
   y += parent.getTop();
   parent = (View)parent.getParent()
}
```

These code may be help you, because I didn't test it. I hope it would work.