# detect if views are overlapping

Tags: android, view

I have problem with drawing views on another size screens! 
I need method which has two parameters of View type. And return true if first view overlapping on second view, and false in another case!

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: try using different layout

Comment: are you using different layouts for different screen resolutions?

Comment: I can't change layout, it's wish of client!

Comment: No, using one layout! Width of first view can change dynamically

Comment: This is the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047970/5749914.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Berserk thanks you for help!
After some experiments I wrote method which detect view is overlapped or not for my case!

```
private boolean isViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {
        int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
        int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

        firstView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
        secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

        int r = firstView.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[0];
        int l = secondPosition[0];
        return r >= l && (r != 0 && l != 0);
    }
```

Comment: Does this cover all the corners?

Comment: Yes, but I don't checking it. This solution good for me. Try for you.

Comment: This is only valid for two views that will always be horizontally aligned, but does not work when the views could not overlap due to horizontal separation. In short, this only works to test vertical overlap.

Comment: @LoungeKatt This method is testing horizontal overlap, not vertical overlap. Notice we are dealing in width and x-coordinates.

Comment: @Elliott Regardless, it is limited to a single axis. That was the point.

Comment: Correct me if i wrong, but i think this method checks if firstView overlaps secondView, but doesn't check if secondView overlaps first.

Comment: **This method doesn't work reliably. Test your code properly before posting / using this.**

Answer (score 31):

You can also use Rect.intersect() to find overlapping views.

```
    int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

    firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
    secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

    // Rect constructor parameters: left, top, right, bottom
    Rect rectFirstView = new Rect(firstPosition[0], firstPosition[1],
            firstPosition[0] + firstView.getMeasuredWidth(), firstPosition[1] + firstView.getMeasuredHeight());
    Rect rectSecondView = new Rect(secondPosition[0], secondPosition[1],
            secondPosition[0] + secondView.getMeasuredWidth(), secondPosition[1] + secondView.getMeasuredHeight());
    return rectFirstView.intersect(rectSecondView);
```

Comment: Be careful to check if both views are visible and return false otherwise, or NullPointerException will be thrown in getLocationOnScreen

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to the answer from [Marcel Derks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38853907/461982), but was written without the need for an additional import. It uses the basic code that forms `Rect.intersect` without creating the `Rect` objects.

```
private boolean isViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {
    int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

    firstView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
    secondView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

    return firstPosition[0] < secondPosition[0] + secondView.getMeasuredWidth()
            && firstPosition[0] + firstView.getMeasuredWidth() > secondPosition[0]
            && firstPosition[1] < secondPosition[1] + secondView.getMeasuredHeight()
            && firstPosition[1] + firstView.getMeasuredHeight() > secondPosition[1];
}
```

You are not required to force a view measurement, but it is done for good measure ;)

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin, you can use the View class extension. It turns out a more compact solution:

```
// Returns true if the view overlaps another view.
// Additionally checks whether another view will overlap if it is shifted to delta values.
fun View.isOverlap(other: View, deltaX: Int = 0, deltaY: Int = 0): Boolean {
    val thisXY  = IntArray(2).apply { getLocationOnScreen(this) }
    val otherXY = IntArray(2).apply {
        other.getLocationOnScreen(this)
        this[0] += deltaX
        this[1] += deltaY
    }
    return thisXY.let { Rect(it[0], it[1], it[0] + width, it[1] + height) }
        .intersect(otherXY.let { 
            Rect(it[0], it[1], it[0] + other.width, it[1] + other.height)
         })
}

// usage example:
if (myView.isOverlap(otherView)) {
    // do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are asking for code to your problem. I am posting the logic which I think may work:

1. Create a funtion which will take two views as parameters, and returns a boolean.
2. Now check the location of both views on the screen using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623919/2944070). It will give you the idea whether they are overlapping or not.
3. Return true or false according to it.

Comment: Thanks you for the posts you answer! I will try implement like you said. If solution will be working good, I'm will write code here!

Answer (score -4):

To help you in a VERY simple way. I will give a logic code which will undoubtedly detect two colliding views, even if they are moving. This can work for Bitmaps, ImageViews, and just about anything you can think of. Here it is and this is all:

```
//LET'S SAY WE DETECT IF PLAYER COLLIDES WITH ENEMY
if((Math.abs(yourviewid.getY() - yoursecondviewid.getY()) < 75) 
     && (Math.abs(yourviewid.getX() - yoursecondviewid.getX()) < 75)){
    //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
}
```