# Is there a way to identify (get an event hook) when a custom view is hidden behind another view in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom view and i wanted to do some change on the view if any other view comes on top of it like opening a dialog box or any other view.

How can i know if anything is overlapping on my custom view ?
How much part ( in %) of my view is actually hidden because of overlapped view?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer from smail2133
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26294475/2354845

Comment: This is the manual check. Means I have to run this check. But I want some kind of event because dynamically some view can overlap on my custom view. Its like when i am scrolling the page some other view may overlap on my custom view and when i scroll further overlapped view will be removed. So, its completely dynamic.

Comment: Even i may not be knowing the overlapped view for checking the overlap using the given solution.

Comment: @Badr Can I get view based on screen Coordinates ( in px ) in Android ?