# Check If a view is completely hidden by other views (not window)

Tags: android, view

I have two views A and B. View B is completely covered view A which means the bounding rect of view B is more than bounding rect of view A.

The best example I can give is, I have a fixed bottom tabs layout and a RecyclerView with multiple linear layouts. When I scroll, one of the linear layout will be behind the bottom tabs layout.

So, How can I programatically check If view A is completely **covered by other views (other views might not be known upfront)**?

Is there any possible way to identify this?

**Update:**
I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252710/detect-if-views-are-overlapping). But it didn't solve my problem. In my case, the view bounds are exactly matching and I want which view is on top.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252710/detect-if-views-are-overlapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of struggle, I have found a way to identify if view is overlapped by other views in the following way.

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain();
viewA.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(nodeInfo);

if (!nodeInfo.isVisibleToUser()) {
    // View is not visible to user. This also validates if viewA is overlapped by other views
}

nodeInfo.recycle();
```

Comment: is this a costly operation or can be called frequently?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following method it will help you to find view overlapping**:-

```
private boolean isYourViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {
        int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
        int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

        firstView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
        secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

        int r = firstView.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[0];
        int l = secondPosition[0];
        return r >= l && (r != 0 && l != 0);
    }
```