# How to check if layout is covered by another layout?

Tags: android

On top of the screen I have a Grid Recycler layout and it has height wrap content. So on start it has 1 row of items. In the middle of the screen I have a button. So I am starting adding items in recycler and number of rows increases 1 then 2 then 3 etc... So I want to know the point when my recycler view will be visually "UNDER" button because number of rows in grid is too much.

So is there a way to check if the view is covered by another view?

Comment: not sure if what you're asking makes sense because the recycler doesn't move, it is either permanently behind or above the button, so you're really asking how to check if the content of the recycler is above the button and i don't think that's going to be possible, perhaps what you can do is just use an average, after 5 items my recycler and button will clash, etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your item `layout_height` is wrap_content along recyclerview, there is a possibility recyclerview takes one item to fill up the screen or more than 100. However, you can check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252710/detect-if-views-are-overlapping) and explore other answers.

```
private boolean isViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {
        int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
        int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

        firstView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
        secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

        int r = firstView.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[0];
        int l = secondPosition[0];
        return r >= l && (r != 0 && l != 0);
    }
```