# Save Imageview With textview to bitmap

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

Currently i'm making a photo editor app. I have activity where you can add a text to the image. I need to save image with text in bitmap. I've already tried to save drawing cache, but the problem is that it saves image in bad quality. Original image  4032*3024 when i save it uses size of imageview which are 1517 * 1137. I've tried to scale bitmap up to original size but quality is too bad. Now i'm trying to draw original bitmap on canvas then to draw text on same position as it was on View. 
`float x = editText.getLeft() * (scale);
float y = editText.getTop() * (scale);
canvas.drawText(editText.getText().toString(), x, y, tp);`
 But for some reason text is not on the same place. I've tried using density to get coordinates but it also don't works.

```
 <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/add_text_color_picker_relative_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_photo_add_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit_photo_add_text_main_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_photo_add_text_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_edittext"
            android:hint="Поле для текста"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is java code:

```
public Bitmap createImage(View view, int imageViewId, int textViewId, Context context){
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(imageViewId);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    float bitmapRatio = (bitmap.getWidth()) / bitmap.getHeight();
    float imageViewRatio = (imageView.getWidth()) / imageView.getHeight();

    float scaleW = bitmap.getWidth() / imageView.getWidth();
    float scaleH = bitmap.getHeight() / imageView.getHeight();
    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(textViewId);

    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    TextPaint tp = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    tp.setTextSize(editText.getTextSize()*density);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int[] xy = {0, 0};
    editText.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    float x = xy[0] * (scaleW);
    float y = xy[1] * (scaleH);

    canvas.drawText(editText.getText().toString(), x, y, tp);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();

    return bitmap;  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.
When i'm calculating screen scale

`float scaleW = bitmap.getWidth() / imageView.getWidth();`

I'm dividing to integers and receiving wrong value;
Instead of it there should be

`float scaleW = (float)bitmap.getWidth() / (float)imageView.getWidth();`

and then you can draw at right position of canvas.

Answer (score 1):

`editText.getLeft()` and `editText.getTop()` gives coordinates relative to their parent while `canvas.drawText()` takes absolute coordinates (with respect to root) as argument.

You should take absolute coordinates of editText (with respect to the root element in your hierarchy). To find out absolute view coordinates, you can use view.getLocationOnScreen() or view.getLocationInWindow(). Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i've tried. Now on the X-asis its on the right place, but Y-asis a little big higher than it should be? Maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: Did you tried with both view.getLocationOnScreen() or view.getLocationInWindow(). Also, try other method in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623829/get-position-of-view-with-respect-to-top-most-parent-in-android?rq=1

Comment: No it only works when image is in portrait size, when height is bigger than width, in landscape it is in the wrong place.

Comment: If none of these work, Can you upload code of your XML layout. Thanks

Comment: Hey, why are using coordinates of editText. Since you want to draw text on image, shouldn't you be using absolute coordinates of ImageView. Tell me if I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: I have a Relative layout, in which image and over image i have edit text, which i can move on touch. You know like in all apps, you can write some text place it on image and it will be saved. And i'm trying ti save image with text together, merge them. Like here https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kCvglnQArEDuP88SNNgBUsTRuA3JatLADFlE-vvYPJ_3eEAet2qQ0aRAlrY-_DpjbA=h900

Comment: Got you !! I am unable to figure out the problem. Let me try it on my system.  Thanks

Comment: I will be helpful if you could also upload code of your Canvas object creation. There are 2 ways to do that, I don't know which one you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152571/discussion-between-ipauler-and-sachin-aggarwal).